# SoapUI: automation of testCase

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I have a request report in SoapUI and i need to run it for a for a given number of values. I am passing these values in parameterized form through a Setup script (java code). Following are the XML elements-

```
<a:long>${#TestCase#Acc1}</a:long>
<a:long>${#TestCase#Acc2}</a:long>
```

and so on (10 such Accounts)

and this is the java code (in SetupScript of TestStep)-

```
context.fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\v-ribha\\Desktop\\test.csv"))

//test.csv contains ',' separated account numbers with 10 in each row/line

firstLine = context.fileReader.readLine()


 while(firstLine!=null)
 {
 String[] propData=firstLine.split(",")

testCase.setPropertyValue("Acc1",propData[0]);
testCase.setPropertyValue("Acc2",propData[1]);
testCase.setPropertyValue("Acc3",propData[2]);
testCase.setPropertyValue("Acc4",propData[3]);
testCase.setPropertyValue("Acc5",propData[4]);
testCase.setPropertyValue("Acc6",propData[5]);
testCase.setPropertyValue("Acc7",propData[6]);
testCase.setPropertyValue("Acc8",propData[7]);
testCase.setPropertyValue("Acc9",propData[8]);
testCase.setPropertyValue("Acc10",propData[9]);

firstLine=context.fileReader.readLine()
 }
```

The code and script are running but the problem im facing is that the report is being run only for the last set of 10 accounts (last line in test.csv), i.e the java code is looping through all lines in test.csv and only the last line's report is getting generated.

How do i make it run for each line and generate a subsequent report (for each row/line of 10 accounts)?

Comment: The question is little confusing. Can you please update the quest with the detail? Like how the data is - each row containing 10 accounts or total 10 accounts in the data. And is the problem only in reporting or execution it self? And how does the request that needs the account data look like?

Comment: The issue has been resolved..thanks a lot :) I have a new question...if you could help me with that then it'd be great! :)

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497480/groovy-script-and-property-transfer-in-soapui