# Groovy Script and Property transfer in soapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

Is there any way in which I can run a `Property Transfer` step from a `groovy script`? Both are in the same test case.

*Test case contains the following test steps:*

1. groovy script
2. soapUI request (GetAccountNumber)
3. property transfer step (transfers a response property from above to a request property in the below step)
4. soapUI request (DownloadURL)

*I need to make sure that the flow is as follows:*

1. Groovy runs and reads numbers from a file and passes them to GetAccountNumber.
2. GetAccountNumber runs with the passed values and generates a response.
3. This response is passed by the property transfer step to DownloadURL.
4. DownloadURL runs with this passed value and generates an output.

All I need to do is run the Property Transfer from the groovy because the other steps can be run from groovy.

It isn't running with the following code

```
def testStep_1 = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("PropertyTransfer") 
def tCase_1 = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["SubmitGenerateReport"] 
def tStep_1 = tCase.testSteps["PropertyTransfer"] 
tStep_1.run(testRunner, context)
```

Comment: What is the problem running for Property Transfer step when other can be done?

Comment: it isn't running with the following code-  
` def testStep_1 = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("PropertyTransfer");  
 def tCase_1 = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["SubmitGenerateReport"];  
 def tStep_1 = tCase.testSteps["PropertyTransfer"];  

tStep_1.run(testRunner, context);`

Comment: @RikarnobBhattacharyya I edit the question adding the code you put in the commit `:)`

Comment: Why do you call the test steps in a groovy script? SoapUI is supposed to execute your test steps.

Answer (score 5):

Without more context I think that your problem is a simple typo, you get your testCase and assing to `tCase_1`:

```
def tCase_1 = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["SubmitGenerateReport"];
```

However then to get the `tStep_1` you use `tCase` instead of `tCase_1`:

```
def tStep_1 = tCase.testSteps["PropertyTransfer"]; tStep_1.run(testRunner, context);
```

Additionally if the `testStep` you want to run from groovy are in the same `testCase` you're executing; you can run it simply using:

`testRunner.runTestStepByName('some teststep name')`

Which I think it's more convenient than get the `testStep` from the `testCase` and then run it.

Hope it helps,